# How to discover allergies to certain foods?

Tags: allergy

Sometimes it is hard to find food allergies. Wheezing or any side affects but the root cause may not be known.

Is there a good way to find food allergy?

Comment: What about scheduling an allergy test?

Comment: Also what country are you in? That might be relevant for what options are available?

Comment: Living in india.

Comment: If you are having anything like wheezing to any foods, GO TO THE DOCTOR for an allergy evaluation ASAP.  Don't mess around with potential anaphylaxis!  It's a reaction that usually happens in seconds to minutes after ingesting a substance to which your body has a serious allergy, but in some cases has taken longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people might recommend that you could have a diary of foods consumed and when symptoms of allergies occur, and by eliminating causes one by one, whatever remains will be the food you are allergic to.

If symptoms of the allergy include a **difficulty of breathing or eye/lip or throat swelling, do not do this, under no circumstances, but go straight to the doctor.**

You might have a **potentially deadly anaphylactic shock** if you suddenly consume a lot of the allergen (by trying to eliminate other causes). Apart from that, this method is unreliable and will take a long time.

### Tests

Multiple allergy tests exist, and depending on your insurance and location, healthcare providers might cover the tests for you.

1. Various skin tests.
   [Further discussion of the 3 most common skin tests at Medlineplus.gov](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/003519.htm)
2. Various blood tests.
   [Further discussion of blood tests at American Association for Clinical Chemistry](https://labtestsonline.org/understanding/analytes/allergy/tab/test)

Basically, there’s no way around getting together with your GP and discussing this matter. The GP will advise you which test to take.

Comment: The test shows allergy in general but it didn't resolve the problem. It says air allergy and some sort of foods which is of tartness...

Comment: We cannot carry an air purifier always as it is not possible in reality

Comment: In allergy testing, there is no test that says "allergy in general."  If your doctor did testing without telling you what to do about it, go back to the doctor for an interpretation and treatment plan.  There are medications (from nasal sprays to pills) that help reduce reactions to environmental allergies.  But your doc needs to tell you what your individual issue is.

Comment: However @Narusan food logging is actually what we DO recommend people do when they can't pinpoint which item in their food is causing allergy symptoms because it isn't always necessary to go to food allergen testing if it's easy to identify by diary.  But since he said wheezing, I agree that he should go straight to testing. I might recommend editing your question to say "Go straight to a doctor if a food causes you wheezing or any other sign/symptom of anaphylaxis like eye/lip or throat swelling, difficulty breathing etc." They can test you without having to ingest the food and risk dying.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Updated.

Comment: @DoctorWhom yes you are right..they gave nasal sprays to reduce environmental allergies and it is good..but wanted to get rid of it..is there a way to permanently cure the environmental allergies?

Comment: @Kathir There‘s not really a cure for allergies.